# How to know all attributes of "Canvas" in react-three-fiber?

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I read the official document of Canvas in react-three-fiber.

[official document of Canvas in react-three-fiber](https://inspiring-wiles-b4ffe0.netlify.app/1-canvas)

There's only few attributes of Canvas. I saw someone's project. There are more attributes he uses in his code like:

```
<Canvas
      concurrent
      noEvents={false}
      pixelRatio={window.devicePixelRatio}
      camera={{ position: [0, 0, 2.5], fov: 69 }}
      gl={{ antialias: true }}
      onCreated={({ gl, scene }) => {
        gl.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping
        gl.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding
        //scene.background = new THREE.Color('#373740')
      }}>...</Canvas>
```

so, how can I know the full introduction about Canvas in react-three-fiber?

Comment: You should take a look at source code, e.g. : https://github.com/react-spring/react-three-fiber/blob/v4.2.20/src/canvas.tsx#L86

Comment: im sorry that website is still around, it's not official.  the full documentation is on github: https://github.com/react-spring/react-three-fiber/blob/master/api.md all props listed. btw you dont need that colorspace stuff anymore, just pass the colorManagement flag and it will set that colorspace and auto correct colors. as for all the props on "gl", that's threejs, the "WebGLRenderer" in the threejs docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you don't have access to documentation or source files, just try outputting the JavaScript object to the console with `console.log()`. For example:

```jsx
var c = <Canvas>...</Canvas>
console.log(c);
```

Then open your developer console, and you'll see an object with all its available properties, public methods, and anything else you may have access to.

Comment: I can't find the public methods in that object

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation on GitHub.  Here's a link specifically for the Canvas component.

https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber/blob/master/markdown/api.md#canvas

This page describes the API of react-three-fiber.

Answer (score -1):

#### get the refrence of the canvas

```
const myCanvas = useRef();
console.log(myCanvas);

<Canvas ref={myCanvas} >
   ......
</Canvas>
```

get the reference then console out